# There's a way I can write javascript inside a PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is there a way I can write javascript code inside a PDF? That for example gives a window.alert when opened in the browser?

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: Checkout the [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)  - app.alert is bottom of page 101

Comment: @phuzi but that alert will work on the browser? or only if opened with acrobat

Comment: I'd guess that would depend on browser implementation and how the PDF is viewed.

Comment: Also javascript can be disabled in Adobe Reader. So no guarantee there, either, that the alert shows.

Comment: Other than Internet Explorer, Acrobat JavaScript will not run when the PDF is viewed in the browser.